# Using sum and max together in sql script

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have updated the query ,but now the error coming is :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS max_parameter_value
                      FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve' at line 7

```
    SELECT sum(max_pv) SUM_MAX,
       sum(min_pv) SUM_MIN,
       sum(max_pv) - sum(min_pv) DIFF
  FROM (SELECT t.parameter_value, t.created_date, t.meter_id, parameter_id
          FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve t
         INNER JOIN (SELECT meter_id,
                           MAX(parameter_value) max_pv AS max_parameter_value
                      FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve
                     where created_date like '2013-01-01%'
                       and created_date <= '2013-01-01 20:00:00'
                       and meter_id between 1 and 16
                       and parameter_id = 1
                     GROUP BY meter_id) q ON t.meter_id = q.meter_id
                                         AND t.parameter_value =
                                             q.max_parameter_value) MAX_TBL,
       (SELECT t.parameter_value, t.created_date, t.meter_id, parameter_id
          FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve t
         INNER JOIN (SELECT meter_id,
                           MIN(parameter_value) min_pv AS max_parameter_value
                      FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve
                     where created_date like '2013-01-01%'
                       and created_date >= '2013-01-01 20:00:00'
                       and meter_id between 1 and 16
                       and parameter_id = 1
                     GROUP BY meter_id) q ON t.meter_id = q.meter_id
                                         AND t.parameter_value =
                                             q.max_parameter_value) MIN_TBL;
```

This is the query that I have written to find the max. Now I have to sum all the `max(parameter_value)`. Similarly I have to find the `min(parameter_value)` for `created_date like '2013-01-01%' and created_date >='2013-01-01 08:00:00'` and subtract these two values.

How to do that?I am using mysql.

If i find sum seperately like foll ,i get a sum but when i do "select sum(min_parameter_value) "it throws field unknown error .Is this sum correct ?i have a doubt?

```
SELECT sum(parameter_value) from

(SELECT t.parameter_value,t.created_date,t.meter_id,parameter_id
    FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT meter_id, min(parameter_value) AS min_parameter_value
                        FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve where created_date like'2013-01-07%'and created_date >='2013-01-07 08:00:00'and meter_id between 1 and 16 and parameter_id =1
                        GROUP BY meter_id) q
            ON t.meter_id = q.meter_id
                AND t.parameter_value = q.min_parameter_value)min_tbl;
```

Comment: Should the other two conditions (`and meter_id between 1 and 16 and parameter_id =1`) also apply when looking for the MINs? If so, you could just add `MIN(parameter_value)` to the same subquery, then make necessary calculations on them in the main query, no?

Comment: @AndriyM:I have updated the question .can you please refer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.parameter_value = q.max_parameter_value THEN t.parameter_value END), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.parameter_value = q.min_parameter_value THEN t.parameter_value END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.parameter_value = q.max_parameter_value THEN t.parameter_value END) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.parameter_value = q.min_parameter_value THEN t.parameter_value END) AS substract
FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve t INNER JOIN
 (SELECT meter_id, MAX(CASE WHEN created_date <= '2013-01-01 20:00:00' THEN parameter_value END) AS max_parameter_value, 
                   MIN(CASE WHEN created_date >= '2013-01-01 08:00:00' THEN parameter_value END) AS min_parameter_value 
  FROM  parameter_values_archieve
  WHERE created_date like '2013-01-01%' and meter_id between 1 and 16 and parameter_id = 1
  GROUP BY meter_id) q ON t.meter_id = q.meter_id
```

Simple example [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95248/14/0)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
SELECT sum(max_pv) SUM_MAX,
       sum(min_pv) SUM_MIN,
       sum(max_pv) - sum(min_pv) DIFF
  FROM (SELECT t.parameter_value, t.created_date, t.meter_id, parameter_id
          FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve t
         INNER JOIN (SELECT meter_id,
                           MAX(parameter_value) max_pv AS max_parameter_value
                      FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve
                     where created_date like '2013-01-01%'
                       and created_date <= '2013-01-01 20:00:00'
                       and meter_id between 1 and 16
                       and parameter_id = 1
                     GROUP BY meter_id) q ON t.meter_id = q.meter_id
                                         AND t.parameter_value =
                                             q.max_parameter_value) MAX_TBL,
       (SELECT t.parameter_value, t.created_date, t.meter_id, parameter_id
          FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve t
         INNER JOIN (SELECT meter_id,
                           MIN(parameter_value) min_pv AS max_parameter_value
                      FROM tcs.parameter_values_archieve
                     where created_date like '2013-01-01%'
                       and created_date >= '2013-01-01 20:00:00'
                       and meter_id between 1 and 16
                       and parameter_id = 1
                     GROUP BY meter_id) q ON t.meter_id = q.meter_id
                                         AND t.parameter_value =
                                             q.max_parameter_value) MIN_TBL;
```

Comment: ,not working....SAYS TO USE RIGHT SYNTAX NEAR "-sum(min_pv) DIFF
  FROM (SELECT t.parameter_value, t.created_date, "

Comment: @user1896796: Remove the preceding `SUM_MAX`.

Comment: @Orangecrush: You absolutely didn't need to use another subquery, you could simply throw in `, MIN(parameter_value) min_pv AS max_parameter_value` to the existing one.

Comment: @ Andriy M: I didn't get you ,I removed all the sum_max,sum_min aliases.But now it gives column max_parameter_value does not exist.   could you please give an example.

Comment: @AndriyM For the minimum value, user1896796 wanted the time be to greater than 20:00, while for the max value, the time was to be less than 20:00. That is why the second sub-query. Hope I understood the question correctly. And you are right, SUM_MAX was not required in the select. My bad while copy+pasting. Edited and corrected it now.

Comment: @Orangecrush :I have updated the script like you said but error is coming.please check.

Comment: @user1896796: I meant only the one erroneously put alias inside the expression referenced in the error message. It directly preceded `- sum(min_pv) DIFF`, and Orangecrush has now fixed that.

Comment: @Orangecrush: You are perfectly right, I missed that bit. You could still use a single subquery and involve conditional aggregation, since it's only a small part of the complex condition that is different. But I realise that these things usually need to be tested & compared first. At least I can see now that it was impossible to just add MIN() to the subquery without changing other things. Thanks for correcting me.